What does "would" in "would I have gathered" mean in Matthew 23:37?
From Matthew 23v37 ESV

"O Jerusalem, Jerusalem, the city that kills the prophets and stones those who are sent to it! How often would I have gathered your children together as a hen gathers her brood under her wings, and you would not!" [My emphasis]

Does "would" here mean Jesus is exerting his resolved will to gather into salvation or is he merely expressing a desire?
.

Jewish rabbis also have the doctrine of grace.

If Jesus wants them to come .. elects them to come .. yet they don’t come , a denial of the doctrine of Irresistible Grace ?

It should say above ..’is it a denial of the doctrine of Irresistible Grace’ ?

Are you asserting that your own personal experience (thus far) is that you, yourself, are not chosen by God, but rather you have made a choice, yourself ?

I’m asking because I want to see if anyone can explain why there is a contradiction between .. How oft would I have gathered you and you would not ..and Irresistible Grace .

@mark danks I think that you could edit this question to make it work well. If you delete from "His will" and replace it with say, "Does 'would' mean  Jesus is exerting his will to gather into salvation or is he merely expressing a desire?" Then click on Flag to bring it to the moderators attention.

@mark danks As you see I have changed your question  so that hopefully it can be reopened. I have tried to keep to the essence of your original question but if you think that I have missed the point then please edit out what I have put. Forgive me if I have taken your time unnecessarily.

[In order to make this answer fit a hermeneutical site I intend to avoid general discussion about irresistible grace, and concentrate on the meaning of one Greek word which I consider to be at the heart of the matter: thelo]
Matthew 23:37 ESV

"O Jerusalem, Jerusalem, the city that kills the prophets and stones those who are sent to it! How often would I have gathered your children together as a hen gathers her brood under her wings, and you would not!"  My emphasis.. would/ethelesa

NET Bible: "I have longed to gather". I have longed/ethelesa
NASB 1977 "I wanted to gather". I wanted/ethelesa
We can have a desire, a longing, which has not grown into a resolve; have desires but not do anything about them until an appropriate time.
Matthew 1:19

"And her husband Joseph, being a just man and unwilling to put her to shame, resolved to divorce her quietly."  willing/thelon. resolved/eboulethe

Joseph had a desire and this came to be a firm resolve.
From Luke 22:42

"Father, if you are willing, remove this cup from me. Nevertheless, not my will, but yours, be done".

Again   "boulei/willing" is contrasted with "thelema/will".
Helps Word-studies-

1014 boulomai [resolutely plan] is a strong term that underlines the predetermined [and determined] intention driving the planning [wishing, resolving]. In contrast 2309 [thelo] focuses on the desire[wishfulness] behind making an offer".

From Isaiah 30:18

"yet the Lord longs to be gracious to you; therefore he will rise up to show you compassion,..Blessed are all who wait for him".

The Lord longs now[at present], which leads to doing something in the future.
Jesus would/desired/longs/wished to gather but later on e.g. in Acts 2:41 he does gather:

"and there were added in that day about three thousand souls".

In Isaiah's time many years before Pentecost God was longing to be gracious. Jesus' longing[thelema] turns into His Sovereign  action of actually saving in His timing.

..thank you .. I appreciate your answer .. I’m reading and re-reading .. I feel Jesus is lamenting the loss of souls during His time on Earth ..because they would not come to Him ..But I like your point that people did eventually come to Him .. so I’m weighing what you have said .. thanks again .

Could be a challenging subject. Without reiterating what many have already studied over the centuries and the world at large, I believe this man's scriptural approach warrants attention on this subject: https://www.amazon.com/Elect-Son-Robert-Shank/dp/1556610920  Robert Shank also wrote "Life in the Son" to clearly understand how perseverance of God's chosen fits clearly within scripture overall without contradictions.

Thank you for all answers and the above ..from Rob Callicotte ..
